# The safer function to remove diacritical marks in android (all versions)

Tags: java, android, diacritics

I've got 3 functions to remove diacritical marks and I will use one of them in my Android app.

The first one has a disadvantage of not working with android 2.2 and below.

The second seems good, but I don't know how safe it will be when used in a wide variety of devices.

The third one I wrote, since the *only* diacritical marks I will have to deal are the ones inside the array.

I will use this function for small search strings of no more than 10 bytes. Search is a major function of my app so I need a reliable solution. Will the second option really work in all devices?

FIRST:

```
    public static String removeDiacriticalMarks(String string) {
        return Normalizer.normalize(string, Form.NFD)
            .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
    }
```

SECOND:

```
    private static Map<Character, Character> MAP_NORM;
    static {
        MAP_NORM = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
        MAP_NORM.put('á', 'a');
        MAP_NORM.put('à', 'a');
        MAP_NORM.put('ã', 'a');
        MAP_NORM.put('â', 'a');
        MAP_NORM.put('é', 'e');
        MAP_NORM.put('ê', 'e');
        MAP_NORM.put('í', 'i');
        MAP_NORM.put('ó', 'o');
        MAP_NORM.put('ô', 'o');
        MAP_NORM.put('õ', 'o');
        MAP_NORM.put('ú', 'u');
        MAP_NORM.put('ü', 'u');         
        MAP_NORM.put('ç', 'c');
    }

    public static String removeAccents(String s) {
        if (s == null) {
            return null;
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);

        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            Character c = MAP_NORM.get(sb.charAt(i));
            if(c != null) {
                sb.setCharAt(i, c.charValue());
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

THIRD:

```
    static Character charswap[] = {'á','a','à','a','ã','a','â','a','é','e','ê','e', 'í','i','ó','o','ô','o','õ','o','ú','u','ü','u','ç','c'};

    public static String removeSWAP(String s) {
        if (s == null) {
            return null;
        }           
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < charswap.length; k+=2) {
                if (s.charAt(i) == charswap[k]) {
                  sb.setCharAt(i, charswap[k+1]);
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The second seems completely reliable to me. It also seems a lot more maintainable than the third (because it is a lot less cryptic about what's going on). It's probably faster as well.

Comment: Do you think it will work in all android devices regardless of their language and regional settings?

Comment: @Daniel - I don't see anything in the code that would be affected by language or regional settings. I suppose you might have an issue if the string contained base characters and combining diacritical marks as separate characters (e.g., `"a\u0301"` instead of `"á"` or `"\u00e1"`), but that depends on how the string is generated, not on the language or region. To cover this possibility, you might want to modify the above code to skip individual combining marks themselves if they occur separately.